# SQL Query Results to Local Variable without unique identifier

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm relatively new to SQL and I'm trying to write a query that will assign the result of multiple rows into a local variable

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @x= (SELECT someCol
              FROM table)

--Does important stuff to the @x variable

SELECT @x
```

During my research I realized that this won't work because the subquery can only return one value and my query will return multiple results. However I can not do something like this:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @x= (SELECT someCol
              FROM table
              where id= 'uniqueIdentifier')

--Does important stuff to the @x variable

SELECT @x
```

The reason I can't use a where clause is that I need to do this for the entire table and not just one row. Any ideas?

EDIT: I realized my question was too broad so I'll try to reformat the code to give some context

```
SELECT        col_ID, col_Definition
FROM            myTable
```

If I were to run this query col_Definition would return a large varchar which holds a lot of information such as the primary key of another table that I'm trying to obtain. Lets say for example I did:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @x= (SELECT  col_Definition
              FROM myTable
              WHERE col_ID = 1)
   --Function to do the filtering of the varchar variable that works as expected
   SELECT @x as [Pk of another table] --returns filtered col_Definition
```

This will work as expected because it returns a single row. However, I would like to be able to run this query so that it will return the filtered varchar for every single row in the "myTable" table.

Comment: Why do you need to put all rows into 1 variable? Why not use a temp table?

Comment: The only reason I want to put it in a variable is so that I am able to filter the results. The data inside of "someCol" is a varchar that is quite long and holds the primary key of another table deep inside of it. So I'm using the variable to do filtering the work and then displaying the filtered results. This works for a single row but I have no idea how to approach it with multiple rows. I'll look into using a temp table though! @WEI_DBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you store a PK embedded in a string that you want to eventually get out and use to join to that table.  I would think putting the group of records you want to work with into a temp table and then applying some logic to that varchar column to get the PK.  That logic is best as set based, but if you really want row by row, use a scalar function rather than a variable and apply it to the temp table:

select pk_column, dbo.scalarfunction(pk_column) as RowByRowWithFunction, substring(pk_column,5,10) as SetBasedMuchFaster
from #tempTable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what the 'uniqueIdentifier' is first.
Not sure about using a subquery and grabbing the result and executing another query with that result unless you do an INNER JOIN of some sort or if using python or another language to process the data then use:

```
("SELECT someCol
          FROM table
          where id='%s'" % Id)
```